# Custom Data Source Spring MVC Hibernate 3

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, datasource

I'm developing a Spring MVC application with Hibernate and I'm facing a problem with the connection to the database.

I have defined the datasource in my `web.xml` using `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` and set the properties of the schema that my application is connecting to, like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>  
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>  
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>  
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>  
</bean>
```

But, now I want to use a custom dataSource, cause (for security reasons) I have a table in the database with a "connection chain" that contains the dataSource properties (url, username,password, etc) encrypted so I don't need to set the properties manually in my xml, just passed them through that "connection chain".

I don't know if I'm confusing people but I don't speak english very well and I'm totally desperated.
Thanks and regards.

**EDIT:** 
Thanks for quick reply!

Sorry about the poor information.
Well at a first time my app connects to a generic schema in the database with a generic user and password (username: "hello", password:"hello), where it's placed a table containing the "connection chain" of various applications including mine.

That connection chains contains the user, password, url and MaxConnections.

Thanks again.

Comment: Can you clarify? It sounds like you want to connect to a database to read values that will let you connect to a database. I'm assuming you're using more than one database?

Comment: Maybe it is not what are you looking for, but if you want to encrypt your properties (username, password, url) you can do that in properties. Use "jasypt" library as explained here: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/HOWTO+Use+Jasypt+to+encrypt+passwords+in+configuration+files

Comment: @superEb I have edited my question. Is it clear? Ask me what else I need to add. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring contains a security feature which handles users, databases hashing and sessions. You should use an authentication manager defined in your security configuration file and create a bean to handle the getting of users from the table.

```
<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"
class="com.program.service.CustomUserDetailsService" />

<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

You can then define your user details service as follows to get your users using Hibernate 3 from a database which should already be configured.

```
package com.program.service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.program.dao.UserDAO;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.program.model.User domainUser = userDAO.getUser(login);

    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    return new User(domainUser.getUsername(), domainUser.getPassword(),
            enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,
            accountNonLocked,     getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId()));    //get role id of domain user
}

public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
    return authList;
}

public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {

    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (role.intValue() == 1) {
        roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
    } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
        roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
    }
    return roles;
}

public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (String role : roles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
    return authorities;
}

}
```

Your database should be configured in application.properties as follows:

```
#DB properties:
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/program
db.username=root
db.password=password

#Hibernate Configuration:
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
entitymanager.packages.to.scan=com.program.model
```

This will allow you to use a login form as follows to login users from your database.

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>">
<table border="0px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
                    <tr>
                            <td><spring:message code="login.login"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username"
                                size="30" maxlength="40" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td><spring:message code="login.password"/></td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password"
                                size="30" maxlength="32" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                    </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

I wouldn't recommend using a Connection chain. I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for the reply! I knew about spring security but in this case i can't use it, for authenticate users i have a stored procedure in the database. And my problem (my boss problem) is that we don't wanna put the credentials of the database in the application, as I said before we just wanna put a generic user connecting to a schema where it's placed a table with the chain connection details. Thank you for your recommendation, i will try to persuade my boss.